# Binding a text box value with condition in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am using asp form view. I want to bind a text box value based on condition.

```
<td style="height: 12px; 
            border-right: silver 1px solid; 
            border-top: silver 1px solid;
            border-left: silver 1px solid; 
            border-bottom: silver 1px solid;">

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtHaulZoneCodeLEM" 
            runat="server" 
            CssClass="cagText" 
            Text='<%# Bind("HaulZoneCodeLEM") %>'>
    </asp:TextBox>

</td>
```

I have tried this:

```
<asp:TextBox 
    ID="txtHaulZoneCodeLEM" 
    runat="server" 
    CssClass="cagText" 
    Text='<%# ((TextBox) Container.DataItem).HaulZoneCodeLEM != 0 ? ((TextBox) Container.DataItem).HaulZoneCodeLEM : string.Empty %>'>
```

How to resolve this?

I moved to code behind :

```
 <td style="height: 12px; border-right: silver 1px solid; border-top: silver 1px solid;
                                        border-left: silver 1px solid; width: 339px; border-bottom: silver 1px solid;">

       <asp:TextBox ID="txtHaulZoneCodeLEM" runat="server" CssClass="cagText" Text=ConvertHaulZoneCodeForDisplay('<%# Bind("HaulZoneCodeLEM") %>')>                      
                                        </asp:TextBox>

                                    </td>
```

In My code behind page I wrote like this :

```
 Protected Function ConvertHaulZoneCodeForDisplay(ByVal str As String) As String
        If str = 0 Then Return ""
    End Function
End Class
```

Still I am getting error in the aspx page..

Comment: view my form view code up here http://pastebin.com/t7WMDjNA

Comment: Wow thats a lot of code. I agree... Move it over to the codebehind.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Error 9 Name 'Bind' is not declared.

Comment: Error 1 The server tag is not well formed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible for you to consider using  `event` instead of `method`? 
There, you can check the value of the textbox and you can modify it. 
Whatismore, if you are binding data to textbox from a datasource, I suggest you to use data binding event.
for more info : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.databinding.aspx